# Using RPi as internet accessible backup server for multiple PCs

Tags: ssh, backup, owncloud

I currently have a 3TB hard disk attached to my RPi running a samba server which several family laptops/PCs using [Aomei](http://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html) backup to.

My plan is to allow internet access for these machines to continue back up their incremental backups when they are not local.

I see that allowing the samba to be internet accessible is a very bad idea, so I have researched some options:

1. Samba (discounted)
2. [Owncloud](http://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-owncloud/)
3. sshfs (not being updated)
4. ftp (not secure, slow)
5. sftp
6. VPN + samba (complicated, might be over the top)

Before I get started testing out each of these methods, does anyone have any warnings, preferences or suggestions? I need to be able to continue these backups from windows machines!

Thanks

Comment: `sshfs` is basically `sftp` in the different coat. Both has pro being secure, but for one-way dropping files I would recommend the `sftp` method, since the FS stuff is not much useful overhead in this use case.

Comment: Preferably I'd like to be able to view the folders/images in a remote Windows machine like samba. But I'll probably go for sftp if those two are pretty much the same. Thanks

Comment: Once you will have `sftp` set up, you can use also `sshfs` if you want to access backups "like local". But I would not use `sshfs` it as a primary method of doing backup.

Comment: Hello. The instructable link given in bullet 5 explains how to setup an *ordinary* ftp server and dyn-DNS services, despite its title "Secure FTP Server"... Just to be aware.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with Jakuje about the usefulness of `sshfs` vs. `sftp` particularly if you'd "like to be able to view the folders" in a file browser.  I don't have any numbers, but neither one is likely to have a speed advantage.  I'd say sftp is actually *somewhat pointless* and the major reason it exists is compatibility with old methodologies (file transfer vs. remote filesystems).

Answer (score 1):

I would use rsync: it can use ssh keys for authentication. So for backup you just need to have ssh access from the (non-local) machine to the pi, and use something like `rsync -vr /some/folder my_user@my_pi.some.domain:/storage/backups/`

Comment: Windows doesn't have an rsync function and I need explorable images

Comment: I don't think there's a reliable solution that will give you both stable backups and an ability to view them as a filesystem.There's a windows application called [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) which fully supports the rsync protocol and ssh keys. Then, whenever you need to "explore", you can use something else, maybe a web server with a [file manager](http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Does rsync make disk/partition images? I myself have a more complicated backup routine: 2 disks, 2 oses and a massive partition of which I only want to backup some folders.